# In Rails, ActiveRecord-based query returns a different set for Postgres and other database types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**This is using Ruby 2.3.3 with Rails and ActiveRecord 5.1**.

Taking this query as an example.

```
    Quizz
    .select('questions.id as qID, questions.text as qTEXT, answers.id as aID, answers.text as aTEXT')
    .joins(:questions => :answers)
    .where(id: quizz_id)
```

When testing against a **SQLite** database, in a development environment, it correctly returns a collection of hashes containing the fields I have chosen to select.

When testing against a **Postgres** database, in a production environment, it wrongly returns a collection of *Quizz* objects with only the field `id`, which is set as `Nil`.

Some important things to note:

- The output query is the exact same for both cases.
- I have tested the query generated (using to_sql) directly in the Postgres database and it works perfectly. In fact, if I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query.to_sql)` using the Postgres database, the results come out as expected.

I have searched and couldn't find a reason why it's behaving differently.

**SOLUTION EDIT:**

I can't answer the question because it's tagged as a duplicate. Turns out, as according to this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1600670), Postgres will automatically lowercase any field that isn't quoted. So the correct query for Postgres would be:

```
    Quizz
    .select('questions.id as "qID", questions.text as "qTEXT", answers.id as "aID", answers.text as "aTEXT"')
    .joins(:questions => :answers)
    .where(id: quizz_id)
```

Also, as @muisshort noted in the comment section, inspect won't show those fields but they are there.

Comment: In short: if you `q = Quizz.select('...').joins(...).where(id: quizz_id).first` then you can `q.qID`, `q.qTEXT`, etc. and it should work. Just because `#inspect` doesn't show the aliased columns doesn't mean that they're not there.

Comment: Hey @muistooshort, thanks for responding. I actually took the time to debug in the first place because it wasn't working.

When I do

`collection.each {|i| i.qTEXT}`

It raises an exception saying the property isn't there. I tried both accessing the property directly or via the hash operator, neither succeeded.

It only worked when I used select_all, as described in the question.

Comment: What does `query.to_sql` say?

Comment: I think it might be because Postgres isn't conserving the capitalization I'm specifying for the fields in the query. So I will try accessing those fields in lower case and report back here if it works.

Comment: Hey @muistooshort, that was exactly it. Postgres converts all fields into lowercase if they aren't quoted. I'll close the question and post the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I reopened if for you since there were two issues in play (the duplicate and the case sensitivity). You can answer your own question if you'd like, you figured it out after all.